# How to handle spectial characters in Tritium

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I'm working on a Spanish site using MoovWeb & Tritium but I am having issues with special characters.
For a content, wherever there are special characters, it always jumbles them up and show blocks or question-mark character. I don't have access to the source code of original site so I cannot determine if the site was using proper HTML-safe alternatives for special characters.

Is there any way to manage or handle special characters in tritium easily instead of doing some kind of find & replace routine?

Answer (score 0):

While developing locally, you will have the source of the original site in the tmp/messages directory of your project. This is the raw response from the origin server, so any special encoding or character bytes will be preserved. If you can determine the bytes that make up the special characters, you can use Tritium's `replace()` function to change these bytes to HTML-safe alternatives. For example,

```
replace(/\xe9/, "&#233;")
```

where `\xe9` is the byte sequence for é.

This is assuming that this character was encoded properly. If not, you'll have to isolate the malformed bytes and replace those one by one.